# correct way of binding data

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

user_model

```
public function rating_data()
{
    $recipe_id = 1;

    $this->db->select('recipe_id');
    $this->db->from('rate');
    $this->db->where('recipe_id', $recipe_id);
    $count_user = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $count_user;
}
```

*main*

```
public function get_rating_data()
{
    $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $rate = $this->User_model->rating_data($postdata);
    echo json_encode($rate);
}
```

*service*

```
get: function() {
    return $http.post("http://localhost/admin-recipick/api/Main/get_rating_data").then(function(result){
        return result.data;
    })
}
```

view

```
<div ng-repeat="rate in ratingdata">
    {{rate}}
</div>
```

I tried using console.log to view the output and it displays what i am looking for but i don't know how to bind datas

controller

```
RatingList.get().then(function(payload) {
    $scope.ratingdata = payload.data;
    console.log(payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function by this

```
  public function get_rating_data()
  {
   $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
   $rate = $this->User_model->rating_data($postdata);
   echo json_encode($rate);
    $scope.resultdata=$rate;
  }
```

Comment: Im getting an error:...................... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\admin-recipick\application\controllers\api\Main.php on line 88.............the resultdata is color violet

Comment: use your code but put {{rate.rate}} instead of {{rate}} because rate is the property of your object

Comment: should i erase $scope.resultdata=$rate; ??

Comment: Is my ng-repeat right?? Because it doesn't display any output

Comment: what is the structure of your object that you are getting  i means what are the properties and verify whether it is an array or single object because ng-repeat only works with array

Comment: ah okay .. it is a single object.. so what should i put instead of ng-repeat?

Comment: just display that object with its properties like {{ratingdata.rate}}

Comment: still nothing displays

Comment: what is the structure of  your receiving  object?

Comment: this is what my console displays:                                                                   Object {data: "3.6666666666667", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: just remove ng-repeat and add only {{rate}} in your div it will start working

Comment: the output is 1instead of 3.6666666666667

Comment: ahhh my mistake just display {{ratingdata}} because you are getting data in {{ratingdata]} if not working then use {{ratingdata.data}}